# IE and mobile safari cut off text.. possibly a line height issue?

Tags: internet-explorer, text, mobile-safari, css, reformat

I've got a page that displays properly (and beautifully) in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera, but very slightly reformats in Internet Explorer and iPhone's mobile version of Safari. Specifically, it's formatting just a little larger than the visible area, resulting in cut off text. It might be a line-height issue. Is there any solution for it? And while we're at it.. what's up with IE's text looking so awkward? I'm a newbie.. they don't support Helvetica??

All suggestions greatly appreciated.

Screenshot:
http://img163.imageshack.us/i/ieformat.png/

HTML:

```
    <div id="bio_left">
     <p class="justify">People often say it's hard to describe the sound of his records and categorizing him often presents an even bigger challenge, but what is truly undeniable and inarguable is that Fernando Garibay is a hit-making producer, DJ and artist. As multi-instrumentalist who plays guitar, keyboards, drums, bass, a formally trained arranger for string and brass sections and a programmer, with a proficiency that rivals top session players but with a uniqueness that only a seasoned "artist" producer yields, he is able to communicate through music unlike anyone else.</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
 font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#202024;
 line-height:120%;
}
```